# broadcast service for incoming sms dosent work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, smsmanager

I use the class below for my SMS receiver. I have no idea what's wrong with it. I heard something about that Google no longer allow SMS permissions after 2018. and only allow to read an SMS with # tag, but unfortunately, I don't get those SMS either.

**JAVA**

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    Toast.makeText(context, senderNum, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see I added all permissions related to SMS and define its own receiver with priority="999"

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<!-- alarm manager -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_intheater" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />


    <activity android:name=".ui.login.Login">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".ui.verification.VerificationActivity"></activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".service.IncomingSms"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter
            android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".service.BootUpService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".service.AutoStart">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name=".service.AlarmService"
        android:enabled="true"
        >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".service.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".service.Alarm"></receiver>

</application>
```

Comment: I guess permissions are not needed anymore.
Have you noticed that the messages app asks for message permission but still shows OTP's. This is it I guess
https://proandroiddev.com/no-permission-required-for-sms-verification-in-android-o-761fe2d4f675

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I didn't check permission from setting -> App -> App name -> permissions

many users don't accept receive and read sms permissions. for having better ux and security, it's better to use https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/user-consent/overview or https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview.
these two methods don't need user permissions for sms and only access to the sms that server send